# Print instantly a number on a qrcode with ZPL and vb6

Tags: vb6, zpl

I have a vb6 code to print a qrcode with ZPL on a toshiba printer, this works perfectly...

But now I would like to print a number on the qrcode, I've seen such things with logos but they used corel, paint, gimg e.t.c. to manipulate the qrcode.

Is it possible to do this in vb6 ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not understanding the use of ZPL on a Toshiba printer.  ZPL (Zebra Programming Language) is a proprietary markup language used on Zebra thermal printers. Can you clarify?

Comment: Also, Are you asking how to add a human readable number in addition to the QR Code?

Comment: The Toshiba use ZPL emulation..I'm asking how to print a text string over the qrcode

Comment: Is your VB6 code outputting ZPL or is it creating an image and sending the image down?

Comment: For those wondering, the QR code standard has varying levels of error correction built in so you can obscure part of the code and it still be readable. The higher level of error correction, the more you can obsucre, but will also create a larger code.

Answer (score 1):

Edited my answer to print a number on top of the QR code.  This will probably make your QR code unreadable in most instances.  Printing one object over another object is just a matter of positioning.

I'm going to assume that the Toshiba is using ZPL emulation.  Here is some sample ZPL code that produces a QR Code and human readable over the top of the QR Code.  Replace QR_CODE_DATA with the data you want in the QR Code.  Replace NUMBER_OVER_CODE with the number you want as human readable.  You will need to adjust the ^FO Field Origin coordinates to match where you want to place the objects on the label.  You will also need to change the properties of the code and human readable for size and dimension.  Positioning is done in dots, so you base the position on the number of dots per inch on your printer.

```
^XA
^FO557,556
^BQN,2,4^FDLA,QR_CODE_DATA^FS
^FT576,632
^CI0
^A0N,68,94^FDNUMBER_OVER_CODE^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```